# Jest error "Promise is not a function" when creating a spy in typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to mock Cloudwatch in AWS using Jest and typescript. I'm having an issue creating a spy for the Cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics() function.

The app code does the following (only relevant lines showing):

```
import AWS, { CloudWatch } from 'aws-sdk';
const cloudWatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
/* build params */
const metrics = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(params).promise();
```

The test code does the following with comments.

```
const mockGetMetricStatisticsOutput = {
  Datapoints: {
    reduce: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 1),
  },
} as unknown as PromiseResult<AWS.CloudWatch.GetMetricStatisticsOutput, AWS.AWSError>;

const getMetricStatisticsSpy = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  promise: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(mockGetMetricStatisticsOutput)),
}); 

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  CloudWatch: jest.fn(() => ({

    /* THIS WORKS, but I cannot spy on the getMetricsStatistics function so TEST 1 fails */
    getMetricStatistics: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      promise: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(mockGetMetricStatisticsOutput)),
    }),

    /* The following two definitions result in the error shown - even though the spy is defined exactly like that above  */

    // getMetricStatistics: () => getMetricStatisticsSpy, /* ERROR, Promise not a function */

    // getMetricStatistics: () => Promise.resolve(getMetricStatisticsSpy), /* ERROR, Promise not a function */
  })),
}));
```

The problem is when trying to use the getMetricsSpy which is defined exactly as the working inline definition of the code. If I try to use the spy as shown in the commented out lines, I get an error in the app code on this line:

```
const metrics = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(params).promise();
```

stating that "promise is not a function". I get this when running the test.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird:

```
CloudWatch: jest.fn(() => ({
```

According to [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options). I'm pretty sure you want:

```
CloudWatch: () => ({
```

`jest.fn()` is a function that keeps track of how it was called so you can test things that call functions. But this api expects a generic function. And it may be interfering with jest somehow.